# How can i create a button in HTML

Tags: button

I tried writing this code. But when i change the location and modify the code it is showing file not found.

I tried changing the code, changing the location of the file.
The button should act as link and redirect the webpage to the link provided.

Comment: Could you please provide the code , what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use button as a link , which redirect to next page ,you can do in below 3 ways.

HTML

You can use plain HTML ,and use `<form>` tag where you specify the desired target URL in the action attribute.Also set CSS display: inline;

```
<form action="https://microsoft.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Google" />
</form>
```

CSS

You can use `<a>` tag in CSS

```
<a href="https://microsoft.com" class="button">Go to microsoft</a>
```

JavaScript

If JavaScript is allowed, set the location.href.

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='https://microsoft.com';" value="Go to Google" />
```

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: It should redirect to another html file

Comment: you can provide your web page path ,in place of https://microsoft.com